# CSS - Class inside another class

Tags: html, css

I'm building a tumblr theme. I have a option where the user can pick the layout style (one or two columns).
I'm not sure how to deal with it on the CSS. I tried adding a class with the layout he picked to content, but it's not working, I'm not sure I can have a class inside another class.

Basically I want the Content div class to define the Container div class.

```
<meta name="select:Layout" content="ClassOne" title="One Column">
<meta name="select:Layout" content="ClassTwo" title="Two Columns">
```

CSS

```
    .ClassOne{ 
  @media (max-width:480px){
    .container{
      width: 250px;
      float: left;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 480px){
    .container{
      width: 300px;
      float: left;
    }
  }
}

.ClassTwo{ 
  @media (max-width:480px){
    .container{
      width: 500px;
      float: left;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 480px){
    .container, .container .photo img, .photoset img, .link, .quote, .text, .chat, .audio, .video, .video iframe, .answer{
      width: 600px;
      float: left;
    }
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="content" class="masthead {select:Layout}">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain your question little more clearly....

Comment: User picks the class (ClassOne or ClassTwo) and the class is added to the first div <div id="content" class="ClassOne or ClassTwo">.

Although it isn't working, I believe I can't have classes inside classes on the CSS, can I?

Comment: {select:Layout} what represent this? you can simply add class="masthead ClassOne ClassTwo" >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that in plain CSS. Your CSS should look something like this:

```
  @media (max-width:480px){
    .ClassTwo .container{
      width: 500px;
      float: left;
    }
  }
  @media (min-width: 480px){
    .ClassTwo .container, .ClassTwo .container .ClassTwo .photo img, 
    .ClassTwo .photoset img, .ClassTwo .link, .ClassTwo .quote, 
    .ClassTwo .text, .ClassTwo .chat, .ClassTwo .ClassTwo .audio, 
    .ClassTwo .video, .ClassTwo .video iframe, .ClassTwo .answer{
      width: 600px;
      float: left;
    }
  }
```

You *can* use nesting in SCSS, though, but you need an SCSS compiler to generate flattened CSS from the SCSS source code before it is sent to the browser. SCSS is mainly a way to write maintainable CSS files, but the browser cannot use them directly.

- See: http://sass-lang.com/ about SASS and SCSS. They are basically the same, but SCSS has a more CSS'y syntax.
- See: http://leafo.net/scssphp/ for a SCSS compiler written in PHP. I've used this one a couple of times and it works quite nice.
- There are JavaScript SCSS compilers, but that's not the way to go. The browser would have to compile the SCSS on every view and it will tremendously slow down the loading of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, a user selects class2 or theme2 and that class name gets added to the content?

You can do that with Jquery, here is an example I did on JS Bin quickly maybe this will help you? http://jsbin.com/cawuvapicage

Below is the Jquery used, the html is pretty simple. theme1 and 2 are links that are clicked, depending on what one you click it will add the correct class name to the container div.

```
 $(function() {
     $( ".theme1" ).click(function() {
        $( ".container" ).toggleClass("style1");
        $( ".container" ).removeClass("style2");
      });
    $( ".theme2" ).click(function() {
        $( ".container" ).toggleClass("style2");
        $( ".container" ).removeClass("style1");
});
```

});